# How to plot consistent discrete data point in a graph that falls within a limited range?

Tags: python, matplotlib, line-plot, data-representation

The data points in the graph are consistent discrete values that are within these values `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` but as you can see in the graph below it's mainly `[3,4,5]`. What is the best way to represent this data?

I tried setting different values of y-limit.

```
ax.plot(a, b)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
ax.grid()
```

edit: The graph is showing throughput in one second range. The numbers are oscillating between 2 and 5 units per seconds. The graph is showing this information already but I was wondering what is the cleanest way to present this?

[image: Example]

Comment: Difficult to answer. Could you be more specific in your question? You could start with a [histogram](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) and a [spectrogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html).
`matplotlib.pyplot.hist`
`scipy.signal.spectrogram`

Comment: Why not make it a scatter plot and use points instead of lines?

Comment: @PetrNovotný The graph is showing throughput in one second range. The numbers oscillating between 2 and 5 units per seconds. I will edit the question clarify it more.

Comment: @BenT scatter could work by showing the thickness of a line. Thanks.